# get soap auth for dpd.com in QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, soap-client

currently i try to connect to dpd and get an auth-key in QT C++. I am stuck and have no further ideas how to fix my issue, maybe you can help. I use qtsoap an currently my code looks like this:

```
    request.setMethod("getAuth", "http://dpd.com/common/service/LoginService/2.0");
    request.addMethodArgument("delisId", "", "sandboxdpd");
    request.addMethodArgument("password", "", "xMmshh1");
    request.addMethodArgument("messageLanguage", "", "de_DE");

    qDebug() << request.toXmlString();

    http.setHost("public-ws-stage.dpd.com");
    http.setAction("http://dpd.com/common/service/LoginService/2.0/getAuth");
    http.submitRequest(request, "/services/LoginService/V2_0/");
```

I try to catch the response with this code

```
connect(&http, SIGNAL(responseReady()), this, SLOT(getResponse()));
```

but the connection always times out. Thank you for your help!!!

In PHP it looks like this, but im unable to transfer it into my qt code:
[send soap request for dpd.com in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37065407/send-soap-request-for-dpd-com-in-php)

Comment: Did you intend to post an actual username/password on an open forum?

Comment: I try to get an authentification-token, so i can run other tasks.